# Variable product bulk discount in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change the product price in Woocommerce, I know that I can make massive changes by clicking on "Filter" and "Edit" to apply one change to every product. That works fine with simple products, but with variable products that do not happen.

Is there a plugin to make those changes?

Comment: I have never heard of any such thing (and it would surprise me, if it existed). :-/

Comment: Yeah... It seems that there is no solution for that.